# Spark SQL specify encoding while saving dataframe as table

Tags: apache-spark-sql, character-encoding, pyspark

can we specify encoding like as below

`df.write.format("text").option("encoding", "UTF-8").saveasTable`

Answer (score 0):

You can --- In case you want to create an external table as well can specify the path as well

```
df.write.option("path", "/some/path").option("encoding", "UTF-8").saveAsTable("t")
```